# discord.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm making a bot in discord.js and ive been trying to fix this

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: "send",
    description: "Send test command",
    nsfw: false,
    execute(message, args, client){

const sendEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`${message.author.tag}` + ' ' + `Asked:`)
        .setDescription(args.join(" "))
        .setColor('#ff0000')
        .setThumbnail(message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dyanmic: true }))
        .setAuthor(`${message.author.username}`)
        .setTimestamp()
        client.channels.cache.get('877718113976746015').send(sendEmbed);
    }
}
```

On the next line I get this

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

This means your `client` isn’t an instance of `Client`. It is undefined. In your execution, you want to make sure it looks like this, with the arguments how you specified

```js
//most command executions look like this, but pay attention to parameter order
command.execute(message, args, client)
```

You may have forgot to provide `client` or provided something undefined. Make sure the value you put as the 3rd parameter is a `Client`.